# Find cells from last month VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

First time asking a question here. I'm very new to VBA and therefore struggling.

I have 3 columns where I list up dates when I have completed a task.
I need to find a way to save all information from last month to a PDF with a push of a button.

But, I can't find a way to only select cells from last month using VBA, and ignoring the cells from current month.

[Date][Names][Results]

Answer (score 1):

### Export Last Month to PDF

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportLastMonthToPDF()
    With ActiveSheet
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=8, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        End With
        .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\Test\Test.pdf"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```